# Improve color contrast in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, scatter-plot

I have a scatter plot with over 13000 pixels which are divided into 50 clusters based on a label. The label in the this case represents the chemical entity that corresponds to the pixel (see image). I color the pixels based on the label by transforming the labels into numbers [0,50] and then changing these numbers into rgb values. While this works, the contrast between adjacent labels is not good enough. For example, in the figure, the first four labels all are blue, while the last seven are brown. This does not help me to distinguish between the labels. Is there a way that I can improve the color contrast between adjacent labels?

```
class_colors=np.arange(0,50) # each integer corresponds to a label
class_colors_float=[]
for i in class_colors:
    class_colors_float.append(round(i/len(class_colors),2))
cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('Paired')  # choosing a color map
rgba=cmap(class_colors_float)   # converting the color map to rgb values


# creating scatter plot
t=ax.scatter(...,cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('Paired'))

recs = []  # creating rectange patches for the legends
# coloring each rectangle according to the label it corresponds to

for i in range(0,len(class_colors)):
  recs.append(mpatches.Rectangle((0,0),1,1,facecolor=rgba[i]))
```

[image]
    plt.legend(recs,classes,loc='best',bbox_to_anchor=(1,0,1,1),mode='expand')

Comment: You can create a colormap with as many colors as you have labels. Either by choosing one of the [available colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/color/colormap_reference.html) or by creating your own, `cmap = ListedColormap(["blue", "green", "salmon", "crimson", ....])`

Comment: I gave : 
            cm =  ListedColormap( ['viridis', 'plasma', 'inferno', 'magma'..]) but it throws an error :" Invalid RGBA argument: 'viridis'" corresponding to: rgba=cmap(class_colors_float) . How do I change these parameters?

Comment: `ListedColormap` expects a list of *colors*, not *colormaps*.

Comment: `Paired` is not the right colormap to distinguish between adjacent items, especially if you have more than 12 items. `Paired` only has 12 distinct colors, and they change stepwise. If you want something where adjacent items have similar colors and all colors are different, try one of the continuous colormaps, like `viridis` or `gist_ncar`. If you don't need all colors to be different, try one of the repeating maps like `flag` or `prism`.